# Equivalent feature in Firefox's developer tools or Firebug to Chrome's Resources tab?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebug

Chrome's developer tools have a feature called **Resources** tab. In some cases, it's very useful. I cannot find it in Firefox. I wonder if there is anything in Firefox's developer tools or Firebug equivalent to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently present in Firefox Developer Tools, but will be starting from Firefox 34, to be released in November. See section *Storage inspector* in the following article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/09/webide-storage-inspector-jquery-events-iframe-switcher-more-firefox-developer-tools-episode-34/

Regarding Firebug, some features are already implemented such as cookies inspection, but some others might require additional extensions. See for instance [Firestorage Plus!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firestorage-plus/) for local and session storage.

Otherwise, you need to use other extensions (not related to Firebug at all) or techniques to inspect things such as the application cache, or IndexedDB content. All depends on what features from the *Resources* inspector of Chrome you are actually looking for.